# Find string within directory path using RecursiveDirectoryIterator

Tags: php, directory-structure

I'm looking for a way to test on a portion of a RecursiveDirectoryIterator's object output.
I know how to identify a folder, but I am new to php and unfamiliar with how to look at the contents of the folder object's path...  Is this possible?

I have the following:

```
foreach($files as $object){
    $indent = str_repeat('   ', $files->getDepth());
    if($object->isDir()){
        //I know this is wrong... here is where I would want to find the string:
        if($object contains 'mystring')){
            echo "%%%-------found the string!\n";
        }else{
            echo $indent, "|| dir: $object\n";
        }   
    }else{
        echo $indent, "-- $object\n";
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace the line

```
if($object contains 'mystring')){
```

with:

```
if(strpos($object->getPathname(), 'mystring') === false){
```

that will search the object's full path for the string 'mystring' and return boolean false if 'mystring' is not part of the path

btw, string concatenation in php is with the dot, not the comma, so you might want to do 
`echo $indent."-- $object\n";` afterwards

Comment: I think you meant '==' instead of '===', correct?? SO won't let me edit this change because there are too few characters.

Comment: no, it's ===. because strpos returns boolean false if the search term is not contained, and 0 if the string starts with the search term. So if you use ==, it may evaluate to "false" even if 'mystring' is part of the string. See the warning in http://php.net/strpos